# Generate JSON report with Cucumber-js 4 when ignoreUncaughtExceptions: false

Tags: cucumber, angular5, e2e-testing, cucumberjs

We are using protractor-cucumber-framework and with latest update to CucumberJs v4.0 the json report is not generating if E2E feature fails on any step - json file remains empty.

This only happens when `cucumberOpts` has parameter `ignoreUncaughtExceptions` set to  `false`. The question is how to generate json report on step failure when `cucumberOpts: ignoreUncaughtExceptions: false`.

`After`, `AfterAll` hooks are not helpful

Answer (score 0):

According to the [protractor-cucumber-framework readme](https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework#uncaught-exceptions), using the `ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true` is the way of handling protractor's uncaught exceptions.

As [mentionned by darrinholst](https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework/issues/98) cucumber would handle this error [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/c525ca6b277a6a8fea43632ae493c13999cddc94/lib/launcher.ts#L186) :

```
      process.on('uncaughtException', (exc: (Error|string)) => {
       let e = (exc instanceof Error) ? exc : new Error(exc);
       if (config.ignoreUncaughtExceptions) {
        // This can be a sign of a bug in the test framework, that it may
        // not be handling WebDriver errors properly. However, we don't
        // want these errors to prevent running the tests.
        logger.warn('Ignoring uncaught error ' + exc);
        return;
       }...
```

Another solution would be to return the promise, that would let cucumber handle the errors and won't need the `ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true` anymore.

This code :

```
Then(/^I can say Hello World$/, function(done: any) {
  this.page
    .sayHelloWorld()
    .then(done);
});
```

Would be written like this :

```
Then(/^I can say Hello World$/, function() {
  return this.page.sayHelloWorld();
});
```